Getting familiar with the definition of martingales.
I am new to martingales. To get familiar and process the new Definition I wanted to do an example.
Definition (Martingale)
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. Suppose $\mathcal{F_0} \subseteq \mathcal{F_1} \subseteq \mathcal{F_2} \subseteq ... \subseteq$ a sequence of sub-$\sigma$-algebras.
We say $X=(X_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is adapted if  $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable.
We say that $X=(X_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a martingal if

for every $n$, $E[|M_n|] < \infty$ .
$E[M_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=M_n$.

Example:
Suppose A_0,A_1,A_2,... are independent and identically distributed random variables s.t.
$P(A_i=-1)=P(A_i=1)=1/2$ for ervery $i$.
Let $X_0:=0$ and $X_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n A_i$.
Show that the sequence $(X_n)_n$ is a martingale.
The first condition is statisfied since,
$E[|X_n|]=E[|\sum_{i=1}^n A_i|]\leq E[\sum_{i=1}^n |A_i|]=n<\infty$.
About the second condition:
Since no filtration is specified I'll use the generated filtration bei $X_n$,
$\mathcal{F}_n:=\sigma(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)$.
But this is the point where I got stuck.
I was thinking about writing $X_{n+1}$ as $X_n +A_{n+1}$ and use linearity to get
$E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=E[X_{n}+A_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=E[X_{n}|\mathcal{F}_n]+E[A_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]$.
The last step should be to show that $E[A_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=0$. But I do not really know how to do so.
My last resort would be to write out $\mathcal{F}_n$ as the $\sigma$ algebra generated by $X_1,...,X_n$.
But I do not even know how the $\sigma$ algebra generated by multiple random variables is defined. If I would guess again I would consider $(X_0,...,X_n)$ as a $n+1$ vector valued function and $\{(X_0,...,X_n)^{-1}(B):B \in \mathcal{B^{n+1}}\}$, where $\mathcal{B^{n+1}}$ denotes the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.
But this seems way to excessive for a "simple" example.
To summarize:
How do I show that $E[A_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=0$?
(Assuming my apprach thus far is correct.)
Alongside that, I would be interested if there is some general and "simple" way to verify if some sequence is a martingale.

Except for a constant $X_n$ I cannot think of a simpler example of a martingale. In fact, historically that was how they were found more than two hundred years ago. Albeit the name "martingale" is due to Doob (around 1950 or so). Hint: $A_{n+1}$ is independent of the $X_1,\dots,X_n,.$

@KurtG. Oh I think I got it now. I could have just calculated $E[A_{n+1}]=0$ to see that E[A_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=0. Is that correct?

Sounds correct.
